# How can i send params to Controller using socket in Sails JS from Android

Tags: android, socket.io, sails.js

I'd like to can send POST params to sails js using sockets, in web version is like this:

```
io.socket.post('/message/send/',{user:'user',message: 'my message'});
```

This params are receiver in Sails JS Controller using req.params but, how can i send this using Android?

I've tried using:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("url", "/message/send");
obj.put("user", "myuser");
obj.put("message", "my message");
mSocket.emit("post", obj);
```

Sails JS has routed good the request to controller Message and action Send but never receive params.

Comment: Can you give more code on what you are trying on Android? Right now all you are showing is the creation of a JSON object.

Comment: I've updated the message.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to a similar problem, all your post data must be sent in a data attribute like :

```
socket.emit('post', {
  url: 'http://myUrl',
  data : myJsonObject
}, function(result) {

});
```

Then in your Sails controller it gets available in :

```
req.allParams();
```

Cheers